# Update date format in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update date field in my table. I am currently getting date value from the form like mm/dd/yy i.e(05/06/13) format. I want the date to convert into Y-m-d (i.e 2013-05-06) format and to update it. I used DATE_FORMAT but the date is not updating .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET    coldate = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(colDate,'%m/%d/%y'),'%Y/%m/%d')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/315b3/1)